# Andriod navigation drawer, не работает кнопка вызова меню

Tags: java, android

Не работает кнопка вызова меню в левом верхнем углу приложения, после того как переключусь на другой экшен в меню.

При старте приложения, устанавливается по дефолту один из фрагментов приложения, и в данный момент, если нажать на кнопку которая вызывает меню, то вылезет менюшка с лева. После, если переключиться на другой фрагмент в этом меню, то кнопка не реагирует на нажатия и менюшка с лева не вылазит, но ! свайпом с лева - на - право вызывается.

Т.е. хотелось бы понять, почему так и где проблема ?

Само приложение создавалось из шаблона в AndroidStudio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/my_audios" android:icon="@drawable/ic_my_audio"
            android:title="Мои аудиозаписи"
            android:checked="true" />
        <item android:id="@+id/popular_audios" android:icon="@drawable/ic_popular_audio"
            android:title="Популярные" />
        <item android:id="@+id/recommend_audios" android:icon="@drawable/ic_recomendation_audio"
            android:title="Рекомендуемые" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Проигрыватель">
        <menu>
            <!--item android:id="@+id/clear_cash" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Отчистить кэш" /-->
            <item android:id="@+id/item_player" android:icon="@drawable/ic_player_audio"
                android:title="Открыть" />
            <!--item android:id="@+id/exit_from_profile" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Выйти из профиля" /-->
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

MainActivity

```
SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.my_audios) {
            MyAudioFragment fragment = new MyAudioFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Мои аудиозаписи");
            //return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.popular_audios) {
            PopularAudioFragment fragment = new PopularAudioFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Поплуярные аудиозаписи");
        } else if (id == R.id.recommend_audios) {
            RecommendationAudioFragment fragment = new RecommendationAudioFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Рекомендуемые аудиозаписи");
       // } else if (id == R.id.clear_cash) {

        //} else if (id == R.id.exit_from_profile) {

        } else if (id == R.id.item_player) {
            PlayerFragment fragment = new PlayerFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Проигрыватель");
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

UPD:

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: Добавьте реализацию `onOptionItemSelected` в вопрос и `Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);` в `onNavigationItemSelected` не нужно. Перенесите это в `onCreate`

Comment: Вообще не понял.

Comment: Дравер открывают в обработчике нажатия на пункты меню в активити.

Comment: Опять не монял. Я как бы только новичек в этом.

Comment: Тот код, который вы привели к вашей проблеме отношения не имеет. Двовер обычно открывают по нажатию на иконку-гамбургер (три горизонтальных полосы). Обрабатывают нажатие на эту кнопку в методе `onOptionsItemSelected()`. Приведите в вопросе код этого метода.

Comment: Добавил остольное из main activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте вот это в метод `onOptionsItemSelected`. Сей код обрабатывает нажатие на иконку-гамбургер и открывает/закрывает дровер:

```
if (id == android.R.id.home) 
{
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

И бесплатный совет - не пользуйтесь шаблонами пока они вызывают вопросы. Т.е. проще изучить как оно работает читая отдельные статьи по дроверу, фрагментам etc.

Comment: Не получается найти эту иконку. R.id.menu - нет такого ID

Comment: @or_die, да, не тот айди вписал. См. обновлённый ответ.

Comment: Спасибо !!!!!!!!!!!!! )

Comment: @or_die, пожалуйста) И в самом деле - забейте на шаблоны - от них прок есть только если вы точно знаете все нюансы. Иначе если что-то не будет в шаблоне реализованно из нужного - замучаетесь его править под свои нужды. Проще с нуля написать. Заодно и в тонкостях разберётесь)

Comment: Понял,  спасибо !)